# Grab control value from separate file in ASP website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have two separate .aspx files that are used in one web page. One for the header and the other for the body. In the javascript for the body file, how would I grab the value of an asp:label control from the header? It's name is "lblName", so I tried simply document.getElementById("lblName").value and I received the error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required
```

This site is written in Visual Basic, so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to do this from the code behind as well.

If I hit F12 in the browser (IE) this is the hierarchy I see:

```
<head>
<frameset rows="147,*" frameBorder="no" frameSpacing="0">
   <frame name="frHeader" id="frHeader" src="DistHeader.aspx?statProducer=0707090003" noResize="noresize" scrolling="auto">
   DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
   <html>
     <head>
     <body topMargin="1" rightMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
       <div class="clsNoPrint">
          <div class="clsNoPrint">
          <table width="100%">
             <tbody>
                <tr class="clsNameBar" width="100%">
                  <td width="*" align="left"> 
                     <span class="clsNameBar" id="lblName" style="width: 100%;">
```

Comment: I don't believe so. How could I tell?

Comment: How do you have two separate aspx files in one page if one isn't in an iframe?

Comment: @NealR - look into code you have in browser (F12 almost in any browser will open developer tools, but you may need to install Firebug extension for FireFox) and check if there is any iframe. Besides, do you see an output of that label in browser when your js code is executed?

Comment: I did that and the two tags that I see are <head> and below that <frameset>. Keep in mind I did not build the website, have just been tasked with updating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was a website that was created almost ten years ago, we had to go up the ladder in the frameset to get the value we were looking for. The code below was the method used

```
var el =  parent.parent.frames("frHeader").document.getElementById("lblName").innerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `runat="server"` on your label than its id in browser will be different from one you see on server. 
You must pass its ClinetID to JS somehow. For instance, with `Page.RegisterStartupScript` or if your JS is a part of aspx file you can do something like this:
`document.getElementById('<%=lblName.ClientID %>')`

Another problem: I guess lblName is `<asp:Lable />` which is converted to span which has no `.value`, but you can use something like this:

`document.getElementById('<%=lblName.ClientID %>').innerHTML`

As you are using frames - depending on where your code is located you need to access frame first:

```
//Chrome, FF
document.getElementById("frHeader").contentDocument.getElementById("lblName") 

//IE (it does not support contentDocument and have document instead)
document.getElementById("frHeader").document.getElementById("lblName")
```

Suppose your code is in outer document, which contains actually contains a frame. But if it is in another frame - you should add `window.parent.` before `document.getElementById`